# The type or namespace name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the 'NamespaceA.NamespaceB' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#

1. For missing namespace, I added a reference to relevant project which contains the namespace.
2. Code detected the reference and go stable

   [image]
3. I then compiled the code.
4. Again, I am getting the same error and the code became like this

   [image]

**Please help ! I have no clue what is going on.** This `ConfigurationManager` is being used since ages in our solution (which has many projects). I have created a project in the solution and there is where I am getting this error

---

I tried these, but didn't help

- [Type or Namespace Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700577/type-or-namespace-error)
- [C# web project complaining about a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246852/c-sharp-web-project-complaining-about-a-class)
- [The type or namespace name 'X' does not exist in the namespace 'Y' - in VS generated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552670/the-type-or-namespace-name-x-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-y-in-vs-gener)

Comment: What namespace you like to add?

Comment: @aliboy38 I added a project which contains  namespace `NamespaceA.NamespaceB`

Comment: you want to add ConfigurationManager namespace?

Comment: `ConfigurationManager` is a class in `NamespaceA.NamespaceB`

Comment: `ConfigurationManager` might be in `NamespaceA.NamespaceB`, but it in no way means that it is contained within the assembly you have referenced. It may well be in another assembly that needs to be referenced as well.

Comment: @pixelbadger I have added reference to a project which has that namespace. And on adding a reference to that project, it gets detected by Intellisense (see snaphot in question). BUt when i build the references go away and error comes and after that Intellisense also cannot find reference

Comment: @SimpleGuy What I'm saying is that there may be *other* dependencies required to reference that one project. If `ConfigurationManager` relied on other classes in other projects, you would need to reference those projects too.

Comment: @Grx70 I resolved it. I went to Project Properties > Application > target Framework as `.NET 4 Framework Client profile`. I changed it to `.NET 4 Framework`

Comment: @pixelbadger Thanks for help. I resolved it in above way. See above comment

Answer (score 1):

For this issue you have to add `ConfigurationManager` namespace to your project.

`ConfigurationManager` is part of `System.Configuration` in .NET. You should add a reference to your project if you want to use `ConfigurationManager` after .NET 2.0. As you mentioned you're using .NET 4.0 so you must add a reference to the `System.Configuration` dll.

Then you should try using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`.

Update : If you have custom made class so you probably made a mistake while making or using the class.

[Read this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx) may help you.

Hope it helps

Comment: This `ConfigurationManager` is custom made class

Comment: maybe that's the problem ? Isn't there a conflict ? If you rename it, does it work ?

Comment: @aliboy38 Thanks for help. I resolved it. I went to Project Properties > Application > target Framework as `.NET 4 Framework Client profile`. I changed it to `.NET 4 Framework`